# Transfer function of this circuit

Tags: diodes

> > Given sinusoidal signal at the input, Find the transfer function for this circuit? Assume that the diodes are ideal.

[image]

0 is less than V_input<5.5 D1 is in forward region and D2 is OFF(b/c V_input-(-V_input)<11, the potential difference between anode and cathode of D2) Hence V_input=V_Output

V_input>5.5 D1 is in forward region and D2 is conducts in Zener region(b/c V_input-(-V_input)>11, the potential difference between anode and cathode of D2), V_output=??

The same happens for the lower half of input with the states of diodes reversing.

Question:

1)I think I have analyzed this circuit incorrectly, where did I go wrong?
2)What is the transfer function for this circuit?
3) is there a systematic procedure to find transfer function of such circuits?

Comment: [Transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) is a concept that is normally only applied to linear systems. Your circuit is not a linear system. So to answer the question, we'll have to know what you mean by the transfer function of a nonlinear circuit.

Comment: I am assuming ideal diodes which have linear relationship for input and output piecewise. By transfer function , I mean how does the output relate to input/What is the waveform of the output?

Comment: Okay, but the waveform is going to pass through the breaks in the piecewise model. So what do you mean by transfer function for a nonlinear circuit?

Comment: I am interested in finding an expression for a function which satisfies V_output(t)=f  [V_input(t) ], so that I can plot its waveform

Comment: A full wave rectified sine wave has a strong 2nd harmonic content. As @The Photon says, the system is non-linear and a TF does not exist.

Comment: @HashirOmer You are looking for the "transfer characteristics" and not for the "transfer function" because the latter only applies for linear circuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Vx is the voltage at the "upper" secondary we'll have -Vx at the "lower" secondary. (You called this the input in your question but the input is in the primary).

If Vx>5.5 then both diodes are ON, one forward and the other in Zener region. The "upper" diode wants Vx at the output, the "lower" wants -Vx+11. Who wins? It depends on the resistance of each path. Assuming diodes ideals and for the transformer equal resistance in upper and lower secondary coils, we have a "tie". Then, assuming this coil resistance much smaller than R_load, the output voltage is simply the average Vo=Vx/2+(-Vx+11)/2=5.5 V.